# How to limit parallelism of multiple long-running operations

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

In my program I have **a set of Links**, let's say **a million**. The requirements are:

1) **Process** the links **in parallel**

2) **Limit** how many of these links will run in parallel.

In the example, we don't care about the execution order of the links but to **ensure the process is finished** with errors or without.

How can I properly ensure the above conditions?

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        start_url_list();
    }

    static void start_url_list()
    {
        HashSet<string> urls = get_url_list();

        Parallel.ForEach(urls, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
            url =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying..:{0}", url);
                var my_url = new Url_Class(url);
                my_url.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Processing url is over");
                //Do stuff with my_url properties
                if (my_url.isError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR:{0} msg:{1}",url,my_url.errorMsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OK:{0} Size{1}", url, my_url.size); 
                }
            });
    }
}

public class Url_Class
{
    public string url { get; private set; }
    public string errorMsg { get; internal set; }
    public bool isError { get; private set; }
    public int size { get; private set; }

    public Host(string url_str)
    {
        url = url_str;
        isError = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //Long Process
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that is not working or you want improved with your current code? And the processing, is it some computation that takes some time or is it more IO related (having to wait for some download for example)?

Comment: It's doing some computations along with a web request. The other problem is that some times I get NullReference Exception.

Comment: Based on the code you provided I can only guess why you get NullReference exceptions (since it probably happens in the Start method). But you should have a look at [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow?view=netcore-2.2). It's a mix between async and parallel that you can use to make processing pipelines. It's better suited for scenario's where you have both IO and compute then using Parallel loops (that are most usefull for compute). See [here](https://michaelscodingspot.com/pipeline-pattern-tpl-dataflow/) for an example.